# How to `derive makeData` a `newType`?

Tags: haskell

I'm updating the C bindings library for Pandoc ([libpandoc](https://github.com/ShabbyX/libpandoc)) and I've encountered an issue that is beyond me. I believe this has to do with template Haskell.

The issue is the following. The original author of libpandoc has done [the following](https://github.com/ShabbyX/libpandoc/blob/master/src/LibPandoc/Instances.hs#L14):

```
$( derive makeData ''WriterOptions )
```

This is apparently important because down the line, the entity that contains `WriterOptions` is given to `Data.Generics.Rep.toRep` which requires it to be derived from `Data`.

The issue is that `WriterOptions` is defined [like this](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/1.13.2/src/Text/Pandoc/Options.hs#L284):

```
data WriterOptions = WriterOptions
  { ...
    ...
  , writerMediaBag :: MediaBag
  } ...
```

and therefore, for `WriterOptions` to derive from `Data`, `MediaBag` also needs to derive from `Data`. Adding the following line to libpandoc:

```
$( derive makeData ''MediaBag )
```

doesn't work however with the following error:

```
src/LibPandoc/Instances.hs:XX:X:
    Not in scope: data constructor `MediaBag'
```

I have successfully used `derive makeData` for other types (for example used by `ReaderOptions`) that were created with the `data` keyword. However, `MediaBag` [is defined with](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/1.13.2/src/Text/Pandoc/MediaBag.hs) `newtype`.

---

My question is, how can I eventually make `MediaBag`, defined using `newtype`, derive from `Data` so that I can successfully derive `WriterOptions` that contains an instance of it?

Comment: Can't you just use `deriving` clauses for all of those these days, using `-XDeriveDataTypeable`?

Comment: Those types are in a library that I don't have access to itself. A developer of pandoc said he could add `deriving (Data)` to those types, but then never did. I would try to give `-XDeriveDataTypeable` (to `cabal build` in libpandoc?) and see what happens. In the meantime, whatever is preventing me from deriving `Data` for `MediaBag`, wouldn't it also prevent `deriving (Data)` or `-XDeriveDataTypeable` to work?

Comment: You can use the `-XStandaloneDeriving` extension to provide the deriving clauses separately without changing the library, e.g. `deriving instance Data WriterOptions`. Using the Template Haskell-generated instances won't work with GHC 7.8+ anyway because it disallows user-written `Typeable` instances.

Comment: I don't understand what all is where, but you need to submit a pull request if you want to get something changed in Pandoc.

Comment: @dfeuer, I guess I would have to do that!

Comment: @hammar, thanks for the info. If I understand correctly, you are saying what I'm doing is eventually futile? If so, I would just go with sending a pull request and try to get that in Pandoc itself.

Comment: @Shahbaz: That's what I'm saying, yes.

Comment: You can do all sorts of things still to make `Data` instances, but `Data` is a subclass of `Typeable`, and you're no longer allowed to write your own `Typeable` instances (because that's extremely dangerous and close enough to useless). It's quite possible, however, that the Pandoc maintainer(s) won't want to derive `Data` for all the type! Deriving `Data` exposes the representation, so if any types are abstract, they will probably prefer to write a `Data` instance with a different representation, if possible.

Comment: @dfeuer, interesting. One of the developers had said "wouldn't be easier if we just derive all of those from Data" or something like this, so I guess they would be fine with it. I'll give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: It looks like most if not all of those are completely exposed anyway, so yeah, maybe no problem.

Comment: @dfeuer It is perfectly possible to standalone *derive* `Typeable`, you just cannot give it a different instance than the default derivation.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, you can, and then when upstream derives it themselves, suddenly you're in crazy land. So yes, you can do that as a short-term measure, but long term pushing it upstream seems to be the only really good approach.

Comment: @dfeuer I keep rethinking the idea that different instances should not conflict with each other if they're both derived the same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem isn't that it's a `newtype`, but that `Text.Pandoc.MediaBag` only exports the *type* constructor `MediaBag`, not the *data* constructor. (Note how it's the latter the error message is complaining about.)

Unfortunately, not allowing deriving `Data` and the like for types with non-exported data constructors is considered a *feature*, since it secures types against users breaking intended data abstraction. So indeed you'll probably need an upstream change as suggested in the comments.

Comment: It makes more sense now!